# Integral determination

Tags: integration

I am trying to figure out this integral:
$\int \frac{x}{(x^2+4)^6}dx$

Substitution:

$t = x^2+4$

$dt = 2xdx => dx=\frac{dt}{2x}$

Then:

$\int \frac{x}{(x^2+4)^6}dx = \int \frac{x}{t^6}\frac{dt}{2x} = \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{t^6} + C = $ but how to continue now?

Answer (score 1):

$$\int \frac{xdx}{(x^2+4)^6}=\frac12 \int \frac{dt}{t^6}=\int t^{-6}dt=\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{t^{-5}}{-5}+c=\frac{-1}{10(x^2+4)^5}+c$$